# Migrating to Meteor 1.7 results in Unknown provider: Meteor.userId( Exception

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, meteor

I'm currently working on a Meteor application that uses AngularJS and ionic as the front-end component. My goal is to migrate it from Meteor 1.2 to 1.8. Now, I'm at a stage to migrate my application from 1.6.1.4 to 1.7.0.5. It works fine in Meteor 1.6.1.4, but the routing stops working when I updated Meteor to 1.7. There is no error at compile time and runtime. However, if I debug my application (either in chrome or vscode) and allow all exceptions to be captured, whenever I try to navigate to other routes, an exception occurs as shown below:

> Exception has occurred: Error
>
> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: Meteor.userId(Provider <- Meteor.userId(
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$injector/unpr?p0=Meteor.userId(Provider%20%3C-%20Meteor.userId(
>
> ```
> at http://localhost:3000/packages/angular_angular.js?hash=73c8bcda9a1c9e883cf9771937278c968a815c22:93:12
> at http://localhost:3000/packages/angular_angular.js?hash=73c8bcda9a1c9e883cf9771937278c968a815c22:4359:19
> at Object.getService [as get] (http://localhost:3000/packages/angular_angular.js?hash=73c8bcda9a1c9e883cf9771937278c968a815c22:4507:39)
> at http://localhost:3000/packages/angular_angular.js?hash=73c8bcda9a1c9e883cf9771937278c968a815c22:4364:45
> at getService (http://localhost:3000/packages/angular_angular.js?hash=73c8bcda9a1c9e883cf9771937278c968a815c22:4507:39)
> at Object.invoke (http://localhost:3000/packages/angular_angular.js?hash=73c8bcda9a1c9e883cf9771937278c968a815c22:4539:13)
> at proceed (http://localhost:3000/packages/angularui_angular-ui-router.js?hash=79e1d21fcfb01f251c0f5481c7058e2896f6bc80:507:42)
> at invoke (http://localhost:3000/packages/angularui_angular-ui-router.js?hash=79e1d21fcfb01f251c0f5481c7058e2896f6bc80:503:26)
> at http://localhost:3000/packages/angularui_angular-ui-router.js?hash=79e1d21fcfb01f251c0f5481c7058e2896f6bc80:482:14
> at $Resolve.resolve (http://localhost:3000/packages/angularui_angular-ui-router.js?hash=79e1d21fcfb01f251c0f5481c7058e2896f6bc80:586:34)
> ```

Here is my Meteor package info:

```
accounts-base@1.4.2
accounts-password@1.5.1
allow-deny@1.1.0
angular-templates@1.0.3
angular-templates-runtime@0.0.1
angular:angular@1.4.8
angular:angular-animate@1.4.8
angular:angular-sanitize@1.4.8
angularui:angular-ui-router@0.2.15
autoupdate@1.4.0
babel-compiler@7.1.1
babel-runtime@1.2.4_1
base64@1.0.11
binary-heap@1.0.10
blaze@2.3.2
blaze-tools@1.0.10
boilerplate-generator@1.5.0
caching-compiler@1.1.12
caching-html-compiler@1.0.6
callback-hook@1.1.0
check@1.3.1
ddp@1.4.0
ddp-client@2.3.2
ddp-common@1.4.0
ddp-rate-limiter@1.0.7
ddp-server@2.2.0
deps@1.0.12
diff-sequence@1.1.0
driftyco:ionic@1.2.4
dynamic-import@0.4.2
ecmascript@0.11.1
ecmascript-runtime@0.7.0
ecmascript-runtime-client@0.7.1
ecmascript-runtime-server@0.7.0
ejson@1.1.0
email@1.2.3
es5-shim@4.8.0
geojson-utils@1.0.10
hot-code-push@1.0.4
html-tools@1.0.11
htmljs@1.0.11
http@1.4.1
id-map@1.1.0
jquery@1.11.10
launch-screen@1.1.1
livedata@1.0.18
localstorage@1.2.0
logging@1.1.20
maazalik:highcharts@0.4.0
meteor@1.9.0
meteor-base@1.4.0
minifier-css@1.3.1
minifier-js@2.3.5
minimongo@1.4.4
mobile-experience@1.0.5
mobile-status-bar@1.0.14
modern-browsers@0.1.2
modules@0.12.2
modules-runtime@0.10.0
momentjs:moment@2.11.1
mongo@1.5.0
mongo-dev-server@1.1.0
mongo-id@1.0.7
npm-bcrypt@0.9.3
npm-mongo@3.0.11
observe-sequence@1.0.16
ordered-dict@1.1.0
perak:mqtt-collection@1.0.4
promise@0.11.1
raix:eventddp@0.0.2
raix:eventemitter@0.1.3
random@1.1.0
rate-limit@1.0.9
reactive-dict@1.2.0
reactive-var@1.0.11
reload@1.2.0
retry@1.1.0
routepolicy@1.0.13
service-configuration@1.0.11
session@1.1.7
sha@1.0.9
socket-stream-client@0.2.1
spacebars@1.0.15
spacebars-compiler@1.1.2
srp@1.0.10
standard-minifier-css@1.4.1
standard-minifier-js@2.3.4
standard-minifiers@1.1.0
templating@1.2.14
templating-tools@1.1.1
tracker@1.2.0
underscore@1.0.10
urigo:cancel-fastclick@0.0.2
url@1.2.0
webapp@1.6.0
webapp-hashing@1.0.9
```

Here is my npm package info:

```
"version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "meteor run",
    "debug": "meteor run --inspect-brk=9229"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^3.19.0",
    "eslint-plugin-meteor": "^4.0.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "7.0.0-beta.55",
    "angular": "^1.7.8",
    "angular-meteor": "^1.3.12",
    "meteor-node-stubs": "^0.4.1"
  },
  "directories": {
    "lib": "lib"
  },
  "description": ""
```

Here is a snippet of the routing component:

```
angular
    .module('myModule')
    .config(config);

function config($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
    // $locationProvider.html5Mode(true); // requires <base> tag!
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise(function ($injector) {
        var $state = $injector.get('$state');

        if (Meteor.userId() == null) {
            $state.go('app.home');
        }
        else {
            var $ionicHistory = $injector.get('$ionicHistory');
            $ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({
                disableBack: true
            });
            $state.go('app.pageMain');
        }
    });

    $stateProvider
        .state('app', {
            url: '/app',
            abstract: true,
            templateUrl: 'client/sideMenu/sideMenu.html',
            controller: 'SideMenuCtrl',
            controllerAs: 'SideMenuCtrl'
        })
        .state('app.home', {
            url: '/home',
            views: {
                'menuContent': {
                    templateUrl: 'client/main/pageHome.html',
                    controller: 'pageHomeCtrl'
                }
            }
        })

        .state('app.pageMain', {
            cache: false,
            url: '/pageMain',
            views: {
                'menuContent': {
                    templateUrl: 'client/main/pageMain.html',
                    controller: 'pageMainCtrl',
                    controllerAs: 'pageMainCtrl'
                }
            }
        })
        .state('app.deviceStatus', {
            url: '/deviceStatus',
            views: {
                'menuContent': {
                    templateUrl: 'client/devices/deviceStatus.html',
                    controller: 'DeviceStatusCtrl',
                    resolve: {
                        currentUser: ($q) => {
                            if (Meteor.userId() == null) {
                                return $q.reject('AUTH_REQUIRED');
                            }
                            else {
                                return $q.resolve();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        })
```

When I inspected Meteor.userId(), it does have the correct value after logging in. This seems to be a [dependency injection issue](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/docs/error/$injector/unpr?p0=Meteor.userId(Provider%20%3C-%20Meteor.userId()). However, I don't know why this is related to Meteor.

Other things that I think are worthy mentioning is that I haven't got time to strictly follow import rules to import Meteor packages as recommended in the [Migrating to Meteor 1.3 documentation](https://guide.meteor.com/1.3-migration.html) and my application does not strictly follow the current recommended [application structure and directory layout](https://guide.meteor.com/structure.html). I'm uncertain if these two factors may cause such issue. Please give me some advice on this issue and tell me if you need more information. Thanks in advance!